# Text overlay border bottom div

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-align

I have three div : div 1 contain image, div 2 has border, div 3 contain text:

```
<div id="div-1">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2">
        <img src="dsc00895-1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
<div id="div-2">
</div>
<div id="div-3">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2">
        <p>abcdefghiklmnopqrst abcdefghiklmnopqrst</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

And css :

```
#div-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#div-1 > .item1, #div-1 > .item3{
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    width: 450px;
}
#div-1 > .item2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#div-1 > .item2 > img {
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
}
#div-2 {
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    border-right: 3px solid red;
}
#div-3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#div-3 > .item1, #div-3 > .item3{
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    width: 150px;
}

#div-3 > .item2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#div-3 > .item2 > p {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

[image]
I want when i change content text of div 3, border bottom of div 2 will be shortened.
I'm using `display : flex` to order column contain text, image and other column to display border. But column 1, 3 to set fixed width so width of column 2 not automatically.

How can i edit css if width of content text is automatically ?

Comment: Sorry, i have just added code to clear.

Answer (score 0):

In css remove flex-grow from #div-3 > .item2 and add flex-grow: 1; to #div-3 > .item1, #div-3 > .item3 and that will fix the problem.

```
 #div-3 {
       display: flex;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    #div-3 > .item1, #div-3 > .item3{
       border-top: 3px solid red;
       width: 150px;
       flex-grow: 1;
    }

    #div-3 > .item2 {

    }

    #div-3 > .item2 > p {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 36px;
       border: 1px solid red;
       text-align: center;
       margin-top: -20px;
    }
```